# Protobuf-net has missing dependency System.Private.ServiceModel

Tags: .net-core, protobuf-net

We have a project that uses protobuf-net for serialising and deserialising our protobuf messages. It builds fine on windows, but on our Linux build environment we seem to end up missing a dependency.

When the dotnet core 2.1 service runs up we get an error of:

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest
>   (xxxx.deps.json) was not found:
>
> package: 'System.Private.ServiceModel', version: '4.5.3' path:
>   'runtimes/unix/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Private.ServiceModel.dll'
>   undefined

How best to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Current workaround is to simply copy this library to desired location on project build event

```
  <Target Name="BuildProces" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' "  
          SourceFiles="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.private.servicemodel\4.5.3\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll"
          DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard2.0\" />
  </Target>
```

There is also **condition** that enables only for Windows OS.